# Can compile in Ubuntu but not in Mac OS X

Tags: c++, compilation

I built a dynamic library (`.so file`) on Ubuntu 12.04. Let's call it `test.so`. I had a `test.cpp` file, which calls some library functions. I first compiled `test.cpp` into `test.o` by:

```
g++ test.cpp -o -c test.o
```

It succeeded. Then I compiled `test.o` into `test.so` by:

```
g++ -shared test.o -o test.so
```

Also succeeded.

I did the similar thing but on Mac OS X.

I first got `test.o` by:

```
g++ test.cpp -o -c test.o
```

Then

```
g++ -dynamiclib test.o -o test.dylib
```

This failed, because I didn't provide the libraries that are used in `test.cpp`. I modified it:

```
g++ -dynamiclib test.o -o test.dylib -L/path/to/libraries -lLibraryName
```

Then it works.

Notice that for the first case, I didn't provide such a path to the libraries and the specific library used in `test.cpp`. Does someone know why I don't need to in the first case but need to in the second case?

Comment: Even though I don't have an explicit answer, it's obvious that both implementations of `g++` are not identical, thus it is expected that these things happen. Just to give you an example, if you were to compile with `OpenGL` on MacOS you would need to pass the `-framework` flag, which isn't the case in Linux. It's probably due to MacOS relying on XCode for these tasks.

Comment: Yes, mac uses clang, and g++ is just an alias. Ubuntu uses gcc. However, even if I used clang to compile the code in linux, it still works. It might not be caused by the compiler, but mostly by the os.

Comment: The OS per se doesn't care about compilers or have anything to say about it, but the compiler default settings are another thing. Compilers usually have a default set of libraries they will use to satisfy dependencies, if needed, and they may very well be very different from one platform to another. So the Ubuntu distribution of the compilers have more default libraries than OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker, with default options, does not behave the same on Linux and OSX.  To get OSX linking to behave more like what you expect on linux, use the following link flag.

```
-Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup
```

Comment: Yes you are right. I tried this and it worked. I no longer need to specify the libraries when compiling the dynamic library. But, do I have to provide the libraries when I want to produce the executables?

Comment: Yes, but that behavior is the same as on Linux.  The executable needs to have all the pieces to work.

Comment: If this answered your question can you mark it as such, otherwise what other information can I provide?

Comment: Excellent!  Glad to have been able to help!